# ListView InsertItemPosition not changing on Databound event

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am using a `ListView` to show user info, stored in a table.  I only want to show one record.

When the user first starts using the site, there will not be an initial record, so I need the `InsertItemTemplate` to be visible. Once a record is inserted, I need the `InsertItemTemplate` to disappear.

Based upon research, I have used the `DataBound` event to check for `ListView.Item.Count` and set the `InsertItemPosition` to either `None` or `LastItem` accordingly. I have also set a label on the page temporarily to display the results of the count.

The label is getting updated correctly. However, the `InsertItemPosition` is not changing until after a second `postback` occurs.  So the result is the opposite of what it should be.  It works correctly when the page loads, but then stays visible after I insert data, and then disappears if I delete the record.  Any help would be appreciated. I have posted relevant code below.

```
protected void ListView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListView1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            lblRecordCount.Text = "DataBound - Records exist";
            ListView1.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.None;

        }
        else
        {
            lblRecordCount.Text = "DataBound - No records exist";
            ListView1.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.LastItem;


        }

    }
```

```html
 Record Count: <asp:Label ID="lblRecordCount" runat="server" Text="Nothing Happened"></asp:Label>
        <br />

        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceGift"  OnItemCreated ="ListView1_ItemCreated" OnDataBound="ListView1_DataBound"  >
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your `ListView` inside `update panel` and then try to show/hide your `InsertItemTemplate`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I ran into a similar issue where it would work initially, then not work.  I believe there may be an error with my logic when I delete the one existing row.  My assumption is that the listview does not execute the databound event if the datasource is empty or there is a timing issue.

Comment: However, your recommendation helped me come up with a backdoor solution.  I did use a updatepanel and 2 separate listviews, each nested in a division.  I toggle between the divisions depending if the listview is empty or not.   For some reason, the timing on making the div visible or not is accurate, similiar to the label, even though the InsertItemPosition did not get updated properly using this same method.